# Subversion - find file in repo

Tags: svn

How can I get the path of one file in a SVN repo?

Suppose I want to find a file named "LoginInterceptor.c" with its complete path in one SVN repository; which command would I use?

Answer (score 4):

You can use svn ls *path_to_repository* (I've just tested with a url ala http://) and grep the output.

```
$ svn ls -R http://myrepos | grep -i logininterceptor.c
```

Comment: you might want to add `-R` option for ls, otherwise it shows just the files in current URI path (svn client 1.6.12)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking for a file that possibly has already been deleted use:

```
$ svn log -v http://myrepos | grep LoginInterceptor.c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) with the "commit database" feature, you can use ViewVC's search form.